# jQuery - How to get a div without an <a> from multiple div's

Tags: jquery-selectors

I'm new to all this so I apologise if my question is 'primitive'. I've looked all over and can't find the answer that suits my specific problem, which is...

I have several div's all with a the same class name and all with individual id's. All but 1 of the div's also contain an anchor tag.

I'm trying to get the id of only the div with an id that doesn't have an anchor tag - how do i do it? - also, I need to do it in a way that would work if I changed which div (with an id) didn't have the anchor, ie I would get the id of whichever div had the anchor removed (only 1 div with an id within the divContainer div would have no anchor).

eg: (occurs with other div's etc on page)

```
<div id="divContainer">
<div id="1" class="div"><a id="a1" class="a" href="blah blah">Blah</a></div>
<div class='other div'></div>
<div id="2" class="div"><a id="a2" class="a" href="blah blah">Blah</a></div>
<div class='other div'></div>
<div id="3" class="div"><a id="a3" class="a" href="blah blah">Blah</a></div>
<div class='other div'></div>
<div id="4" class="div">Blah</div>
<div class='other div'></div>
<div id="5" class="div"><a id="a5" class="a" href="blah blah">Blah</a></div>
<div class='other div'></div>
<div id="6" class="div"><a id="a6" class="a" href="blah blah">Blah</a></div>
</div>
```

I hope that makes sense! Happy to answer any questions needed to help!
Thanks in advance to the guru's with the knowledge to get me out of my hole.

Answer (score 1):

You want

```
$('div:not(:has(a))')
```

Comment: You want `.div`, but otherwise that's it.

Comment: Generally you should separate out the not as well, when the condition is complex: `$('div').not(':has(a)')`. That will be a fair bit faster.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! Your answer did work but I have realised my example wasn't specific enough, my situation is more complex - see edit.

Comment: I found it!! Thanks to SLaks, thirtydot & PaulPRO who got me on the right track. For anyone else who wants the answer here it is:

    $('div.div').not(':has(a)').map(function() { return this.id; }).get(); where div is the name of the class of the div's that you want to search. I'd suggest coming up with a better class name to avoid confusion!!